# jQuery .on click not working for user click

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code set

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#login").on("click",function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
    $("#login").click();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="login" name="login" value="LOG IN">
```

as expected, this code triggers an alert when the document loads with the value of the login button.

however, when i try a manual click with the mouse, it does not trigger.

here is a test i just did: 
[image]

Comment: Make sure include jquery libraray

Comment: It works for me : http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/Q7d5t/

Comment: jquery is already imported

Comment: can you show us a button with id `#login` ?

Comment: please it is a id or class?

Comment: Show the html if possible?

Comment: Does the button always have a value?

Comment: Little tip: press f12. The code, as posted by you, works just fine. The error is elsewhere.

Comment: what are you using as a modal? is it loading an ajax request? try changing `$("#login").on("click",function(` to `$('body').on('click','#login',function(`

Comment: Problem is in your id '#login' coz u just giving dynamic'on('click'' and static 'click' to same id '#login'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your login modal is editing the DOM so cancelling out the event listener..

Change

```
$("#login").on("click",function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Into

```
$("body").on("click","#login",function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

This will work on DOM changes

Comment: Works perfectly now. Thanks. Thing is i tried `$(document).on("click","#login",function(){});` but didnt think of using `body`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the pop up overlaps your button, so the click is not triggered.

When you trigger click it show the alert but before the pop up is loaded, which means that the element on the pop up is not the one that triggers it.

Comment: how would i be able to click the button? cause as you can see it shows that its being clicked but its not triggering the function

Answer (score 0):

You should check your HTML if #login ID is only defined once.

Maybe the login button in your header what triggers the overlay has the same ID!